# Wordpress - Dynamically Process Image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have images uploaded in the media library in WordPress.  I would like to show the images with text composited on top of them using PHP's GD or something similar.

If this were just a plain old PHP site, I could create a URL with a search parameter for the text and center it over my image with GD and serve it up.  In WordPress, I am a little unclear how to accomplish this.  I am not sure if it fits well into the concepts of Posts and Pages.

I can perform the programming myself.  I am just looking for some pointers on how to get started.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in WordPress, too. It's mostly just a plain old PHP site. For example, you could create a PHP file that creates the composite given the text and the image and use it like: `<img src="/composite.php?image=...&text=...">`.

Maybe all of the images are on a particular page or post type. Then you could create a custom page or post-type template that parses the `$post->post_content` for the images, does the compositing, and alters the image tags to point to the new composited images.

Or, more generally in that vein, create a [filter for `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) that does that for all posts.

You might be able to hook into the WordPress upload system. As images are uploaded, you could create the composite. The [`wp_handle_upload` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) might work for that.

Or you could even create a [WordPress cron job](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) that scans the media uploads for new entries and creates the composites then.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into the first 2 options.  The user needs to interactively be able to alter the text, so during upload won't work.  For the first idea, I am assuming that the PHP file would just be part of a theme or plugin.